# Why is database medrec not found by the Avitek sample application?

Tags: weblogic12c

Circumstances: performed a by-the-book developer install using wls1212_dev.zip and wls1212_dev_supplemental.zip. Followed the README.txt and the README_SUPP.txt strictly. Created a sample domain by hand, no issues seen. Executed the run_samples.sh configuration script, no issues seen.

When starting the medrec domain (Avitek sample app) using startWebLogic.sh, the medrec database is not found (specific error below). The Avitek app comes up and display-only pages are navigable, but database touches all fail. The WLS console in the medrec domain works fine. The JDBC data source "MedRecGlobalDataSourceXA" exists in the domain and the fields look ... well, reasonable, to my untrained eye.

For now I am taking the error message at face value and assuming database creation failed within the setup script (run_samples.sh) But I examined all the logs in wlserver/samples after executing the run_samples.sh script, and there was nothing that seemed relevant.

Platform: VirtualBox VM with CentOS 6.5 and JDK1.7.0_45

Other notes: I am aware of the security fix in 1.7.0_51 and higher JDKs that breaks existing Derby database applications. I purposely chose to avoid this issue by installing the 0_45 JDK until I resolve this "database not found" issue.

Grateful for any help.

Error:

```
<May 25, 2014 8:40:46 AM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY.>
<May 25, 2014 8:40:46 AM PDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.>
<May 25, 2014 8:40:47 AM PDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "MedRecGlobalDataSourceXA" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: The connection was refused because the database medrec was not found.
weblogic.application.ModuleException: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: The connection was refused because the database medrec was not found.
    at weblogic.jdbc.module.JDBCModule.prepare(JDBCModule.java:338)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.apache.derby.client.am.DisconnectException: The connection was refused because the database medrec was not found.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseRDBNFNRM(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseAccessRdbError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseACCRDBreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readAccessDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(Unknown Source)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" - Really? How would I know about the Derby bug on JDK1.7.0_51 and higher had not first researched this question extensively, now? That's a fairly obscure bit of information.


Question is "unclear"? It's a specific error on a specific operation.

Question is "not useful"? How to define "useful"? An answer would be "useful" to us, since we have a little go/no go test that runs against Avitek; we had a reasonable expectation it would continue to be usable in 12c.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem and don't know what else to do.

Comment: So, is the only solution using an earlier JDK version ?

Comment: Let me clarify. We've never been able to get Avitek working with WLS 12c, regardless of JDK version. In addition, there's a separate known issue with Derby and JDK 1.7 versions higher than 0_45. So if you decide to address this, I would recommend solving the Avitek problem using pre-0_51 (that is 0_45) JDK, and then separately upgrade the JDK past 0_45 and apply the workaround for Derby. Note: we haven't actively looked at this issue recently, so we have nothing new to add.

Answer (score -1):

In linux unset variable LANG before starting Derby database server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer seems a bit out of context. Can you explain how exactly this would help solve the problem?